# Argument unused during compilation?

Tags: g++, clang

From the research I have done, the problem seems to be with clang. If that is the case, how would I fix this on a Mac? Would switching to Ubuntu/Linux be a better option?

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but my professor is having us code using C syntax using g++ and saving our files as '.cpp' before we dive into C++.

**Warning:**

> clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-ansi'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

**Makefile:**

```
CC = g++

calendar: main.o calendar.o appt.o day.o time.o
    $(CC) main.o calendar.o appt.o day.o time.o -g -ansi -Wall -o calendar.out

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -Wall -c $<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in believing that this warning is issued by clang++ in these
circumstances and not by g++, and that you see it on your Mac because `g++` is
really `clang++`.

The GCC option [`-ansi`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) is meaningful for compilation and not meaningful
for linkage. Clang is warning you because you are passing it in your linkage recipe:

```
$(CC) main.o calendar.o appt.o day.o time.o -g -ansi -Wall -o calendar.out
```

where it is ineffective, and not passing it to your compilation recipe:

```
$(CC) -Wall -c $<
```

The wording of the diagnostic is misleading since it is provoked here
precisely by the *absence* of compilation. Nevertheless, it does
draw attention to a mistake on your part. Remove `-ansi` from your linkage recipe and add it to your compilation recipe.